# Is redering jinja2 template variables as js template literal unsafe?

Tags: javascript, python, jinja2, xss

Is redering jinja2 template variables as js template literal unsafe?

Lets say some python app returns some string or data and we receive it in js block.

For example:

```
<script>
var items = `{{somedata}}`;
</script>
```

Comment: if you don't control what is in `somedata` - ie. user add this string - then it may be unsafe.

Comment: @furas any idea what data would be unsafe in this somedata?